# Get extra value in datatable ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I am filling data by below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

manageTable = $('#manageTable').DataTable({
    'ajax': base_url + 'products/fetchProductData',
    'order': []
  });
```

here I want total assets as well means product_price * qty = assets of all product to show as summary like $100000 assets we have so I changed the controller ad added the new statistics obj and here is the value in assets keys.

and question is how can i show this extra value to this page.

[image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biMFA.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a DataTables function "drawCallback" to get an extra value after the table populated completely with server side json response and further use it for any purpose. Following is the modified code:

```
manageTable = $('#manageTable').DataTable({
    'ajax': base_url + 'products/fetchProductData',
    'order': [],
    'drawCallback': function(response) {
      console.log(response.json.total_assets);
    },
});
```